# Right Paren Missing Error in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm new to using action script, and I'm having trouble making a calculator. Could anyone help?

This is the code:

```
output=0;
function addInput(num) {
  if(accept=="calcText") {
    if(output=="0") {
      output=num;
    } else {
      output=output+num;
    }
  } else if(accept=="new") {
    output=num;
    accept="calcText";
  }
}

function type(type) {
  holder = Number(output);
  accept = "new";
  calcType = type;
}
function calculate() {
  if(calcType=="+") {
    doPlus("+");
  } else if(calcType=="-") {
    doMinus("-");
  } else if(calcType=="*") {
    doPlus();
  } else if(calctype=="-") {
    doMinus();
  } else if(calcType=="*") {
    doTimes();
  } else if(calcType=="/") {
    doDivide();
  }
}
accept="calcText";

on(release, keyPress"+") {
  function doPlus() {
    output = holder+Number (output);
  }
  type("+");
}


on(release, keyPress"-") {
  function doMinus() {
    output = holder-Number (output);
  }
  type("-");
}
on(release,keyPress"/") {
  function doDivide() {
    output = holder/Number (output);
  }
  type("/");
}
on(release,keyPress"*") {
  function doTimes() {
    output = holder*Number (output);
  }
  type("*");
}
stop();
```

And this error is showing up:

`Scene 1, Layer 'Button', Frame 171, Line 63, Column 21   1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before "+".`

`Scene 1, Layer 'Button', Frame 171, Line 73, Column 21   1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before "-".`

`Scene 1, Layer 'Button', Frame 171, Line 82, Column 20   1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before "/".`

`Scene 1, Layer 'Button', Frame 171, Line 91, Column 20   1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before "*".`

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

What you've posted isn't ActionScript. I'm not sure what it is.
Here's the AS version of what I think you want.

```
someButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClicked);
function buttonClicked(e:MouseEvent) {
    trace("You clicked the button");
}
```

Can you post your full source?
Are you working with buttons/objects you've placed on the stage?